# Rails printing the value of a database column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I'm new to rails and I have been experimenting. I have to tables companies and contacts and i have set up the associations and relationship. what I would like to do is this.

Currently, in the contacts table it brings back a number for the value of the company name. What I would like instead is the the value of the company name instead of the number. I have tried changing it from the company_id to company_name - but I then get an error about no method being found. Can anyone help on how I do this.

Comment: When you say " it brings back a number for the value of the company name" what exactly do you mean?  Are you talking about a field called `company_id`?

Answer (score 1):

You can delegate to the company

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  delegate :name, to: :company, prefix: true
end

<%= @contact.company_name %>
```

I assume a contact will always belong to a company, if not add, `allow_nil: true`

If you're looping through them like this:

```
<% @contacts.each do |contact| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= @contact.company_name %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

I doubt you've defined `@contact` as you're looping through `@contacts` calling them `contact` you want

```
<% @contacts.each do |contact| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= contact.company_name %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

I.e. without the @ - you're using a local variable not an instance variable.

Comment: It gave me an error it says it can't find the method in contacts#index

Comment: class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :companies
    
    delegate :name, to: :company, prefix: true
    
end#

Comment: I meant to your question, not to my answer.   In any case I'll update my answer based on that.

Comment: Now I changed my code to your suggestion and that's the error I'm getting after adding your code